# Custom themeing not working after updating 22.04 to 22.10 properly

Tags: gnome, themes, 22.10

After i updated Ubuntu 22.04 to 222.10, the custom themes that i have installed do not work properly anymore.

for example:
in Gnome Tweaks i can set the Dracula theme for Legacy Applications, this changes the theme of Gnome Tweaks. But not for Nautilus and Settings.
When i set the Shell theme then to Dracula as well, nothing changes.

[image]

Does this have to do with the Gnome 43 update and the themes not being updated accordingly yet,
or is this something i can fix myself.

For further questions or information please let me know!

diorcula

Comment: one of the disadvantages of installing an interim version sadly. I do, but only on a scratch PC to test it out or by using `Try Ubuntu` on a live USB. Where mission critical, always best to stick with the LTS versions 

Comment: hmm my case is the opposite.  Themes were not working for me in Ubuntu 22.04 but they started working as soon as I upgraded to 22.10. hmm

Comment: Where did you obtain the Dracula theme? Maybe we could look at it and figure out what's going on.

Comment: @mchid i changed it in Gnome Tweaks tool, like i tried for other themes which all worked fine in 22.04